# How to use mergesort on a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
 
        mid = len(arr)//2
 
        L = arr[:mid]
 
        R = arr[mid:]
 
        mergeSort(L)
 
        mergeSort(R)
 
        i = j = k = 0
 
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i][1] <= R[j][1]:
                arr[k] = L[i][1]
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = R[j][1]
                j += 1
            k += 1
 
        while i < len(L):
            arr[k] = L[i][1]
            i += 1
            k += 1
 
        while j < len(R):
            arr[k] = R[j][1]
            j += 1
            k += 1
    print(arr)
```

Applying this on a list of tuples:

```
tuplelist = [(1, 600), (2, 800), (3, 200)]
```

gives me the typeError:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

The merge sort does function on a normal list of integers. I tried to change it to target the values that I want to merge sort: sorting the tuples in ascending order based on index 1 of each tuple, hence the reason I added: `if L[i][1] <= R[j][1]`, For example.

How do I change my sorting algo so that it works on a list of tuples?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Why do you have all those `[1]` subscripts? You should just be comparing list elements, not subscripting them. And `arr[k] = R[j][1]` replaces a tuple with just the second element of another tuple, so now it's just an integer instead of a tuple.

Comment: I don't see how this function could possibly work on a list of integers. All those `[1]` will fail immediately.

Comment: R[j][1] accesses the part that I want to compare in the tuple. How do I put it in a way it sorts it correctly in the array?

Comment: Change `arr[k] = R[j][1]` to `arr[k] = R[j]`

Comment: Then it doesn't work on a list of tuples. That is the base Mergesort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are replacing the tuple with just its second element, so future attempts to compare the 2nd element of the tuple will fail.

```
                arr[k] = L[i][1]
```

and

```
                arr[k] = R[j][1]
```

Don't use the `[1]` indexes when assigning, only when comparing elements. Change them to:

```
                arr[k] = L[i]
```

and

```
                arr[k] = R[j]
```

Full program:

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr)//2
        L = arr[:mid]
        R = arr[mid:]

        mergeSort(L)
        mergeSort(R)

        i = j = k = 0

        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i][1] <= R[j][1]:
                arr[k] = L[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = R[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1

        while i < len(L):
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(R):
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
    print(arr)

mergeSort([(1, 600), (2, 800), (3, 200)])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 600)]
[(2, 800)]
[(3, 200)]
[(3, 200), (2, 800)]
[(3, 200), (1, 600), (2, 800)]
```

Comment: This doesn't work on a list of tuples, it does  work on a list of integers. I am trying to figure out of to change the algorithm so that it works on a list of tuples.

Comment: I just tested it, it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now undrestand why only change "if L[i][1] <= R[j][1]:" and not the rest, as L[i] takes the whole tuple which is what you want.

Comment: Do you also know how to return the list: arr to use outside the nested functions?

Comment: You don't need to return the list, you're modifying it in place. But you could change `print(arr)` to `return arr`.